# Android push notification sound rings more than once in some device (LG)

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending push notifications from server to devices, but in some devices, the notification sound rings more than once even though the message was only sent once.

In Samsung, Xiaomi, and Asus, it works normally, but in LG Marshmallow, the sound rings more than once.

This my code:

```
NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
        inboxStyle.addLine(message);
        Notification notification;
        notification = mBuilder
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.iconnotif)
                .setTicker(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
                .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.iconnotif)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
        wl.acquire(15000);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Does this happen to *all* LG devices with Marshmallow? Or only to specific device models?